# Manipulating array of object data in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, reduce

So I have a set of data let's say...

```
    {'action': 'tweet', 'user': 'loser', 'message': 'fooboo'}
    {'action': 'follow', 'user': 'loser', 'message': null }
    {'action': 'tweet', 'user': 'loser', 'message': 'hello'}
    {'action': 'retweet', 'user': 'loser', 'message': null}
    {'action': 'tweet', 'user': 'michael', 'message': 'CIA is watching'}
    {'action': 'tweet', 'user': 'michael', 'message': 'HEHEHEHE'}
    {'action': 'follow', 'user': 'michael', 'message': null }
```

and I am trying to iterate through it using reduce and return a list of users with a count of all of their actions so for example

```
    { loser: 
            {
              tweets: 2
              retweets: 1
              follows: 1
            }
    }, michael:
            {
               tweets: 2
               retweets: 0
               follows: 1
            }
     }
```

Here is my code...

```
    let userCount = tweets.reduce(function(users, line, idx) {
       users[line['users']] = users[line['user']] || [];
       let action = line['action];

       users[line.user].push({
         action: users[line.user].action + 1 || 0
       })
      return users
    }, {users: []});
```

My code is not successfully counting or injecting the names of the actions as the key onto the object.  This is what my output data looks like.

```
    { michael: [ { action: 1 } ],
      loser: [ { action: 1 }, { action: 1 }, { action: 1 } ],
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write the code for you? What have you tried and what is it that's not working?

Comment: edited with the current code that I have.  Sorry.  I wish there was an easier way to copy and paste code without having to indent 8 spaces every time.

Comment: You still haven't said what's not working?

Comment: I'm just confused on how to successfully manipulate an object with reduce in this manner.  Every resource online has a very elementary example of it like [2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 4, 5] and returning a count of each of the numbers.  Mine is slightly more advanced.  I can't find a good example with a similar format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with the code you posted, most notably that you're getting confused (I assume) between objects and arrays, given your desired output.

The following achieves what you require, and I've annotated it with comments to outline what is happening.

```js
var tweets = [
  {action: 'tweet', user: 'loser', message: 'fooboo'},
  {action: 'follow', user: 'loser', message: null },
  {action: 'tweet', user: 'loser', message: 'hello'},
  {action: 'retweet', user: 'loser', message: null},
  {action: 'tweet', user: 'michael', message: 'CIA is watching'},
  {action: 'tweet', user: 'michael', message: 'HEHEHEHE'},
  {action: 'follow', user: 'michael', message: null },
];

const users = tweets.reduce((users, tweet) => {
  // Deconstruct tweet to get user and action
  const {user, action} = tweet;
  
  // Add user to users list, if they don't already exist
  if (users[user] === undefined) users[user] = {};
  
  // Increment user action count
  users[user][action] = (users[user][action] || 0) + 1;
                            
  return users;
}, {});

console.log(users);
```

Comment: Thank you.  This was what I was looking for.  Very elegant and clean.

Comment: Yes I do.  It's very simple.  After using ES6 destructuring it's very easy to read.  Thanks for the comments with the explanation.

Comment: If you could also explain why if I change the reduce output to an array at the end it's length is 0 that would be great.  Is there a way to make sure every iteration in reduce returns an object so I have an array of objects?

Comment: An array in JavaScript can only have numeric keys, so when you add a string key, you're adding a property to the array object, not an item to the array itself. You’d therefore need to change the structure of the data.